# What is proper way to write a chrome extension with high I/O usage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a simple chrome extension that uses a lot of I/O requests.

To accomplish this, I used API calls to  `chrome.storage.sync.set` and `chrome.storage.sync.get`, which was a huge mistake.

I loaded my extension and tried it out and ended up with a error that I exceeded my `MAX_SUSTAINED_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_MINUTE quota`.

`storage.set: This request exceeds the MAX_SUSTAINED_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_MINUTE quota.
    at Object.callback`

After re-checking the API, I realized I should have known that I would run into problems. Here is the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/storage.html#property-sync-MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_HOUR) regarding my error.

So...I don't know the right way I'm supposed to make a lot of I/O requests...How should I do it? Is it possible to raise the MAX_SUSTAINED quota? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot raise the quota. However, you can save your settings in some global variable or `chrome.storage.local` and periodically write them to `chrome.storage.sync`.

Comment: Hm. It seems the type of storage I may need is `chrome.storage.local`. Thanks for putting me on the right path!